# Do firing events in C# block the current thread execution?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling

If I'm firing the event:

```
var handler = OnMyEvent;

if (handler != null)
{
    handler(some_info);
}
```

then will the execution thread wait until all suscriber methods return to continue the execution after line:

```
handler(some_info);
```

?

Or events are fired "in another thread", meaning that it automatically goes to the next line after `handler(some_info)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Events are fired on the same thread and it will block until they are completed. Of course the event handling code itself can spawn another thread and return immediately but this is completely different matter.

Also note that events like button clicks in a desktop applications like Windows Forms apps are put on a message queue and will fire one at a time. i.e. if you press a button and then press another button the second button event will not fire until the first is completed. Also the form will not repaint and will be "not responding" because painting the form is also an event.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but is it possible to circumvent this?

Comment: Circumvent what exactly?

Comment: The firing of events on the same thread. If I have 20 handlers to an event, why do I want them to fire in sequence?

Comment: You are free to start a thread (or more probably a task) in the handlers themselves that would result in the actual handler code executing in parallel. Also if you are writing a control you can create an event that fires on a separate thread the same way but that would not be what any reasonable developer would expect.

Comment: Also in case of asynchronous operations you can use the new async/await mechanism to get the whole thing done for you by the framework and the compiler

Answer (score 2):

Events are fired in the thread that raised them.